# Media Queries for iphone 5

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

I was trying to target the iphone 5 with my media queries and the background in landscape does not show up. Since I do not have any special graphics for retina displays i wanted to find out if i can use the same graphic for all with the media querys. How do i target iPhone 5 Landscape orientation?

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
and (orientation : landscape)
{

  #homepage{ 
     background: url('images/480x320_Horizontal.jpg') no-repeat fixed #00314d;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use meta tag to force iPhone to render viewport as device width..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

And now use media query for setting styles for landscape mode, for iphone which is >320px;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 321px){
    /*Style goes here*/
}
```

Comment: I already have the meta name code. For some reason iphone 5 does not display the background image, it works fine till iphone 4s

Comment: @hershey this article might help you http://halgatewood.com/iphone-5-media-query/

Comment: this will also capture all other types of mobile devices that fit this range. were you trying to be iOS specific? if so use something like `only screen and (device-width: 320px)`